# Cannot fix Android Proguard Returned with error code 1 error

Tags: android, proguard

When I try to use proguard in my android application simply adding

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
```

to my project.properties file, the APK export fails with the message 
`Proguard Returned with error code 1`

This is my `project.properties` file

```
target=android-18
android.library.reference.1=../LVL
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
```

This is the error stack:

```
    Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSnapshot: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] Warning: there were 247 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp]   at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    [2013-08-28 18:27:13 - MyApp]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add these lines to proguard config file (proguard-android.txt)

```
    -keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }   
    -dontwarn android.support.v4.**
    -dontwarn javax.activation.**
    -dontwarn javax.security.**
    -dontwarn java.awt.**
    -libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
    -keep class javax.** {*;}
    -keep class com.sun.** {*;}
    -keep class myjava.** {*;}
    -keep class org.apache.harmony.** {*;}
    -keep public class Mail {*;}        
    -dontshrink
```

See [Proguard Troubleshooting](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/troubleshooting.html)

Note that if you use

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
```

Your config file isn't the `proguard-android.txt`  in your project root but the general proguard config file in the android sdk folder.
If you want to use the `proguard-android.txt`in your project root you have to use

```
proguard.config=proguard-project.txt
```

in project.properties file.

Comment: Export everything but seems the app have some problem with contact form.

Comment: _Error: Unknown option '0409' in argument number 1_

Answer (score 3):

Cfr. ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)

The AWT classes are not present in the Android SDK. ProGuard sees some classes that depend on them and warns about them, just like a compiler would do. Since the classes presumably are never really used, you can tell ProGuard to ignore it:

```
-dontwarn java.awt.**
```

ProGuard will then proceed processing the code. You shouldn't add any -libraryjars options.

Answer (score 1):

in your error stack, at the bottom, pay attention to not on 'specify additional jars...'

Review your proguard config for inclusion of the android jar which includes all the referenced missing packages like 'javax' and 'awt' `enter code here`

try adding something like following to your proguard.cfg...

```
-libraryjars  /usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-18/android.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
```

Comment: Must I add these lines in `proguard-project.txt`?

Comment: I have tried to add these lines (editing the android sdk path to match my android sdk on windows) to proguard-project.txt still same issue

Comment: Note: in your project, proguard-project.txt gets wiped every time 'android update project' is run.. Note a good place to store your projects config. Better is to specify diff config at the project level. like 'my-extra-proguard.txt'. Then specify that in entry in 'local.properties'  "proguard.config=my-extra-proguard.txt". You have to append what u want for project to the proguard config in your SDK.

Answer (score 0):

update your progaurd to the latest version 4.10 from this link

http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/proguard/4.10/

unzip the file and replace the content in your android sdk directory (progaud folder in tools directory)

[path to android sdk] \Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard

then try again, you might need to restart eclipse.

Comment: try to add your own proguard config file to your project directory
start with empty config file then export the package and see if the error happens again

Comment: The proguard-project.txt is empty, should I write something inside this file? I cannot see any other proguard config file inside my project

Comment: ok, use this file and modify the line in you project proparities
proguard.config=proguard-project.txt
now you have an empty progaurd file that do nothing, but to make sure that your project will generate the package first of all later you can your progaurd configuration to the file

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully ignored the invalid package errors in eclipse in the following procedure:

right click on the project > Properties > android lint reference > in the search line type "invalid" > and mark the id = InvalidPackage > and on the lower right change severity to ignore.

[image]

Note, its a dirty workaround (I could not make the proguard ignore so...)

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in eclipse. I could resolve it by adding

`-ignorewarnings`

in the progaurd-project.txt