# Proguard Returned With Error Code 1 Without Any Specific Information

Tags: android, proguard

I have problem with proguard, I have tried with many possible solutions but still does not solve my problem.

The only information I get from console is

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
```

nothing more, this is a really bad error message I ever met.

I have set

```
proguard.config=proguard-project.txt
```

and nothing in proguard-project.txt that I believe only a couple of comments.

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html
```

Comment: could you post your proguard-project.txt

Comment: Check your error log it will be having full error. Please post full error log.

Comment: asked so many times before...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511516/android-application-signing-proguard-returned-with-error-code-1-see-console http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208784/proguard-returned-with-error-code-1-see-console http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493608/cannot-fix-android-proguard-returned-with-error-code-1-error  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574922/proguard-proguard-returned-with-error-code-1-see-console http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987105/proguard-return-with-error-code-1-proguard-parseexception

Comment: @Yuvi, sure see updated question. GrlsHu Where is the error log located?

Comment: @Huteri See my answer, if you face any error then let me know.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier to let you know, I have read all of them, but in my case, there is no error log that can explain why the proguard is not running fine.

Comment: Cool just making sure. In future pls add in your question what you have tried, what questions you have looked at etc. It will prevent close votes and help community to provide better info up front. It also help future readers to have related questions linked like that up on the top right of the page. Good luck. (I removed my close vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couples of hours finding the solution, I found the solution. I just moved the proguard.jar to another directory which there is no space in the path, then I edited the proguard.bat in /bin folder to that directory. Eventually, the proguard is running fine and give me the error log that I expected.

Sample script.

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Start-up script for ProGuard -- free class file shrinker, optimizer,
REM obfuscator, and preverifier for Java bytecode.

rem Change current directory and drive to where the script is, to avoid
rem issues with directories containing whitespaces.
cd /d %~dp0

IF EXIST "%PROGUARD_HOME%" GOTO home
SET PROGUARD_HOME=..
:home

java -jar C:\bin\proguard.jar %*
```

Comment: this worked really good for me..as it started showing errors but problem is my console jus cleans up till the time it finishes. i.e i am unable to look at the log as i am using svn

Answer (score 0):

You have commented text file, it should be like this :

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Build using following commands:

```
cd <you project directory>
#update project properties
android update project -t 3 -p .
#clean the code
ant clean
# build the application
ant release
```

Comment: is there any solution without using commands? I have problem installing ant,

Comment: @Huteri Export signed application using eclipse, it will use proguard.

Comment: Yes, that is the only way I do, but it gives me that error.